# PHP date array max continuous dates

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have an array like this:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "2018-02-05"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "2018-02-06"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "2018-02-07"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "2018-02-08"
}
```

I would like to push another date (2018-02-09) to the array, only if the continuous days are maximum 5 with the new date. So pushing `2018-02-09` should be fine, but after that, I shouldn't be able to push `2018-02-10`, because that would be 6 continuous dates. Althouh, instead of pushing `2018-02-10` I should be able to push `2018-02-11`, since there is a free day after the 5.

Comment: What if the array had more dates in it? Would you need to check every possible group of dates the same way?

Comment: These dates are the days of one week, and there should be max 6 dates in it. (5 continous, (1 free space), and 1 other date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function adds the given date if it is in the five continuous days:

```
function array_push_continuous(&$array, $date) {

    // shorcut for array with less than 5 dates :
    if (count($array) < 5) {
        array_push($array, $date) ;
        return true ;
    } 

    // shortcut if the last date is different : 
    if (date("Y-m-d", strtotime(end($array)) + 24*3600) != $date) {
        array_push($array, $date) ;
        return true ;
    }

    // check for last 5 continuous :
    $lasts = array_reverse(array_slice($array, -5)) ;
    $last = array_shift($lasts) ;

    foreach ($lasts as $item) {
        if (date("Y-m-d", strtotime($item) + 24*3600) == $last) {
            $last = $item ;
        }else{
            array_push($array, $date) ;
            return true ;
        }
    }
    return false ;
}
```

Usage:

```
$array = array(
  "2018-02-05",
  "2018-02-06",
  "2018-02-07",
  "2018-02-08",
  "2018-02-09",
);

array_push_continuous($array, "2018-02-10") ; // false
array_push_continuous($array, "2018-02-11") ; // true
array_push_continuous($array, "2018-02-12") ; // true
array_push_continuous($array, "2018-02-13") ; // true
array_push_continuous($array, "2018-02-14") ; // true
array_push_continuous($array, "2018-02-15") ; // true
array_push_continuous($array, "2018-02-16") ; // false
array_push_continuous($array, "2018-02-17") ; // true
array_push_continuous($array, "2018-02-18") ; // true

print_r($array);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2018-02-05
    [1] => 2018-02-06
    [2] => 2018-02-07
    [3] => 2018-02-08
    [4] => 2018-02-09
    [5] => 2018-02-11
    [6] => 2018-02-12
    [7] => 2018-02-13
    [8] => 2018-02-14
    [9] => 2018-02-15
    [10] => 2018-02-17
    [11] => 2018-02-18
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$thisDay = '2018-02-05';
$datesArray = array();
$datesArray[0] = $thisDay;
$count = 1;
while(count($datesArray) < 5){

    $next_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($thisDay .' +'.$count.' day'));
    $dayofweek = date('w', strtotime($next_date));
      if($dayofweek != 6){
        $datesArray[] = $next_date;
        $count++;
      } else {
          count++;
      }
 }

 var_dump($datesArray);
```

U could also set the current date with DateTime

Hope my answer helps u.

Answer (score 0):

with a given date to be pushed , you can use this function .

```
$datToBePushed = "2018-02-10";

if(isNextDate(end($arr), $datToBePushed ) == 'up Next' && count($arr) < 5){
    array_push($arr, $datToBePushed);
}

function isNextDate($lastElement, $datToBePushed)
{
    $dateUp = explode('-', $datToBePushed);
    $str = explode('-', $lastElement);
    if($str[0] == $dateUp[0] && $str[1] == $dateUp[1]){
        if($str[2] !== $dateUp[2] && $dateUp[2] - $str[2] == 1){
            return $continous = 'next';
        }
        elseif($str[2] !== $dateUp[2] && $dateUp[2] - $str[2] == 2){
            return $continous = 'up Next';
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```